# VUEX Getter is Getting Error During Testing: TypeError: this.[method_name] is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs, vuex

I got my component to work with a VUEX store, but during testing, I get the following error:

```
 ● farewell/list.vue › renders all farewells
    TypeError: this.allFarewellsAssociatedWithGreeting is not a function
```

My component, test, and store getter code is posted below.

I updated my component to get the test to pass, but then the actual app wouldn’t work. The component would not render when the store was updated. That piece of code is posted below as well.

Please let me know if there’s anything else I can provide to help troubleshoot. Or if there’s any steps I can take to troubleshoot further.

Thank you for your time in helping out a newbie

This is my component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Associated Farewells:</p>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="farewell in farewells"
        :key="farewell['id']"
      >
        {{ farewell["attributes"]["message"] }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: 'FarewellList',
  props: [
    'greeting',
  ],
  components: {
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("farewells", ["allFarewellsAssociatedWithGreeting"]),
    farewells: {
      get() {
        return this.allFarewellsAssociatedWithGreeting(this.greeting);
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getFarewells();
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("farewells", ["getFarewells"])
  }
};
</script>
```

This is my test:

```js
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Create from "@/components/farewell/list.vue";

describe("farewell/list.vue", () => {
  it("renders all farewells", () => {
    const expectedMessage = "arbitrary message";
    const expectedFarewell = {
      attributes: {
        message: expectedMessage
      }
    };
    let getters = {
      allFarewellsAssociatedWithGreeting: jest.fn(),
    };
    getters.allFarewellsAssociatedWithGreeting.mockReturnValue([expectedFarewell]);
    let actions = {
      getFarewells: jest.fn(),
    };
    let store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        farewells: {
          namespaced: true,
          getters,
          actions
        }
      }
    });
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Create, {
      global: {
        plugins: [store]
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is my store getter:

```js
export const getters = {
  allFarewellsAssociatedWithGreeting: state => greeting => {
    return state.farewells.filter(farewell => {
      return farewell.relationships.greeting.data.id === greeting.id
    });
  },
};

export default getters;
```

This is the version of the component code that would allow the test to pass, but would break the actual application. The component would not re-render with the updated data in the store.

```html
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: 'FarewellList',
  props: [
    'greeting',
  ],
  components: {
  },
  computed: {
    farewells: {
      get() {
        return this.fetchFarewells();
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getFarewells();
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapGetters("farewells", ["allFarewellsAssociatedWithGreeting"]),
    ...mapActions("farewells", ["getFarewells"]),
    fetchFarewells() {
      return this.allFarewellsAssociatedWithGreeting(this.greeting);
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the actual `allFarewellsAssociatedWithGreeting`  getter returns a function that returns an array, but its mock getter returns the array instead of a function.

The fix is simply to make the mock return a function:

```js
// getters.allFarewellsAssociatedWithGreeting.mockReturnValue([expectedFarewell]);

getters.allFarewellsAssociatedWithGreeting.mockReturnValue(() => [expectedFarewell]);
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-test-vuex-getter?file=tests/unit/farewells.spec.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your time and help in solving this.  Your solution led me to the solution for my problem and also understanding more about JavaScript's virtual getter/setter.  Thanks again 